# How can I read analog video signal from a FPV camera with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: analog, adc, video

I want to do a few experiments with video encoding and transmission, so I need to somehow read the analog video signal (PAL or NTSC) in to the computer and process it.

I need to read an analog video signal string by string in realtime than digitalize it, encrypt and translate as digital packet and then assemble it into the image on the receiver side. If some packet is lost, I will not lose the whole video frame.

I know how to do the digital software part, but I don't know how to work with the analog hardware part.

I think that I need some electronic converter between the computer and the analog camera that will provide me with a realtime stream of digitalized strings.

Is it possible to input this signal to Raspberry Pi with an ADC? What ADC can I use?

It can be another computer but I'm trying to understand how to read an analog video signal to choose the proper hardware.

I'm trying to rework [this project](https://www.abcelectronique.com/annuaire/montages/cache/3423/digitaliseur-video-mark-ii.html) to make the faster input. Can I remove cache memory and send its input into GPIO directly?

Comment: Direct sampling would be possible but there are dedicated ICs to deconstruct PAL and NTSC signals and output digital data. Have you looked into any such solution?

Comment: Note that from a software engineering point of view, you would want a relevant set of files containing digitized video, and not use live-captured signal all the time. Repeatability and testability is key for developing low-bug software :) Once your codec works, you can then prove it's fast enough at target frame rates and resolutions and qualities, and once that is proven, you can think about how to connect that to a frame grabber card of some sort. (But that's just a commercially solved problem, and Linux has a standard video device interface, V4L2.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nope. I need an analog strings from camera for signal processing. I think, I can't do it without digitalization. But not set of files because it will produce a huge signal latency that I must to avoid.
So, I need some electronic device between camera and computer (it can be something different, not rpi only)

Comment: I would look for a video capture device that is compatible with the Pi. If none exists, pick a different platform that has what you need.

Comment: Again, I did not say your final system would be based on files. I said that while you're working with the codecs, you would always start with files, measure your implementation in CPU usage, latency and quality, and only after you've shown you can do it "offline", you switch to processing real-time signal

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah, I understood :) Don't keep in mind RPi, I think about Jetson Nano or something now. I'm just trying to understand how to work with analog videosignal now. I think, analog television is an amazing thing and want to learn it deeper

Comment: RPI or Jetson makes no difference at this point

Comment: @MarcusMüller can I use this device?
https://www.abcelectronique.com/annuaire/montages/cache/3423/digitaliseur-video-mark-ii.html
by design it uses memory cache and LPT port but can I send ADC output directly into RPi on the acceptable speed (with quality loss for i.e.)?

Comment: @Robotex um, no. that's something homebrew from 24 years ago ? and since when do RPis have LPT or LPT-compatible ports with acceptable speed for megasamples/s? Maybe just stick with a commercial frame grabber. Nothing wrong with these, as long as they're supported by V4L2, as mentioned above.

Comment: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=24136 From this discussion I have understood a lot in this direction.

Comment: I added mention a frame grabber solution that is supported by V4L2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an RPi wiz, but I don't think an RPi is fast enough for real-time video signal processing.  The NTSC composite video signal bandwidth is 4.2 MHz.  The most common A/D sample frequency is 10.73 MHz (3 x the color subcarrier frequency), and the next most common is 14.3182 MHz (4 x subcarrier).

Analog Devices, Linear Technology (owned by ADI), Maxim (owned by ADI), Intersil, and Texas Instruments all make video-speed A/Ds and have app notes on the subject.  RCA used to make converters for this.  Their semiconductor business was acquired by Harris, then acquired by Intersil, then Renesas.  Their app library might still be available online.

The good news is that this used to be a $1000 problem, and now it is a $10 problem.

This is not a trivial project; there is a mountain of data to process.  Consider a sub-assembly such as a shield, USB dongle, or more highly integrated video processing chips.  These days, this task is often done in a Digital Signal Processor (DSP) chip, but that is a whole different level of programming.

Comment: *I don't think an RPi is fast enough for real-time video signal processing.* it definitely is. especially the newer ones, even without considering the built-in video encoding and decoding hardware. But you're right, you wouldn't be doing that through the GPIOs, but through high-bandwidth buses (USB, I'm not sure whether the newer RPIs don't actually come with dedicated camera interfaces, e.g. CSI). But that wasn't was what asked. An ADC attached via a controller via USB is just as much an ADC.

Comment: I am aware of what was asked.  That's why I mentioned five different product lines and sources of design guidance.

Comment: Hmmm. Sad to hear it.

Comment: On Raspberry Pi OS lite, the CPU scales normally. Between 600 and 1500 MHz.

600MHz is much more than 14.3182 MHz. So, why not?

Comment: @Robotex that comparison makes absolutely no sense at all. Not the least.

Comment: @Robotex that's like saying "I can drive at the speed of the earth rotation around the equator so that it's always noon where I am, because the earth turns 1 times per day, and the motor of my car turns 4000 times per minute, which is much faster". A) the rotations of your motor only indirectly affect your driving speed, and you forget that the earth has a larger radius than your car's wheels and b) you ignore that your motor can apply as much velocity to your wheels as it wants, a car is very bad at driving around the equator, seeing that the equator is mostly in the ocean.

Comment: Robotex - a *way* oversimplified explanation using your logic:  600 MHz divided by 14.32 MHz equals 41.9.  If all CPU instructions are single-cycle (and they are not), that is 42 machine language instructions per video sample.  Exactly how much "video encoding and transmission" can you do in only 42 instructions?

Comment: @AnalogKid Where did you get 3x and 4x times the colour carrier rate? Or rather, even if the signals are sampled at multiples of colour carrier, most video decoder ICs would output a BT.601 stream at 13.5 MHz (or 27 MHz muxed YC) stream for both NTSC and PAL.

Comment: Where?  From the dawn of digital video.  Early digital video devices (Sony, DVI, Telemation) used 3x.  A video A/D was a module larger than a deck of cards.  By the mid-70's, 4x was the standard for "better" equipment.  Early on, a frame synchronizer, a single-frame buffer with independent write and read clocks, was one 6-foot equipment rack.

Comment: BTW, the motherboard clock freq in the original IBM PC was 4x subcarrier.  This was so they got dual use out of one crystal - divide by 3 for the CPU clock (that weird 4.77 MHz) and divide by 4 for the color video adapter.

Comment: Note - early digital video worked with composite, not component signals.  Video, sync, and subcarrier in one continuous analog stream.  Early A/Ds were very expensive, and at first no one could afford 2 or 3 of them in a product.  Broadcast quality 1" digital video recorders using component video appeared in the late 70's with the D1 and D2 standards.

Comment: D1 is component (YCbCr) encoded as BT.656. D2 is composite. The usual way of sending it around is serial coax (270Mbit/s for D1, 480Mbit/s for D2.) D2 didn't come about until 1988.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I needed to look up what an 'FPV Camera' is. These are camera modules that give a 'first-person' view, often used for drones.

And you know what? XY problem. Don't bother with NTSC. R.pi (and since you mentioned it, Jetson Nano too) natively supports MIPI input, and FPV cameras that support MIPI are readily available in the same form factors as NTSC/PAL ones.

Set the MIPI camera to SD video (720x480) resolution and YUV420 output and encrypt that. Your data payload will be about 15.5MB/s for a 30fps stream. YCbCr422 will be 20.7MB.

In comparison, an NTSC signal will want a digitizing rate of 4fsc, or 14.318 MHz. Resolution? Maybe 480x480 if nothing moves, less than that with movement.

If you insist on NTSC, the most straightforward way to deal with it is to use a chip called a **Digital Multi Standard Decoder**, or **DMSD**. The DMSD ICs accept NTSC or PAL composite and produce YCbCr422 digital video at 27MB/s on a parallel port. But beware, these ICs are moving into 'end of life' stage as there isn't much call for them anymore.

You can buy the video capture function as a USB dongle ([example](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4715) [example](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Video-Capture-Devices/ci/14774/N/3545908106)), many going by the name 'EasyCap'. This is a popular accessory for folks wanting to convert VHS tapes to digital. These dongles appear to be based on a chip called the STK1160 from Syntek International (Taiwan), [and there's open-source work related to it](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Stk1160_based_USB_2.0_video_and_audio_capture_devices). Supports 2-channel audio and composite or S-video input.

But guess what? MIPI or NTSC->capture->USB, latency will be the same either way, since data are sent line-by-line. I would argue that the MIPI path will be somewhat shorter since you're dealing with a low-level DMA interface rather than a whole USB stack.

Really, stay away from NTSC and embrace MIPI. Your life will be easier.

At any rate, something else to consider. Inline video compression will add some latency (a few lines for M-JPEG, several frames for H.264) but will allow a lower airlink rate and thus more robust video transmission.

Finally, this project may be of interest to you: https://github.com/oyvindln/vhs-decode/blob/vhs_decode/README.md This is a software decode (or capture) for raw tape signals using an ADC. A sub project for CVBS capture is here: https://github.com/oyvindln/vhs-decode/wiki/CVBS-Composite-Decode